# fetch user's unread mails from Gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I want to fetch unread mails from user's gmail account and send the notification via SMS. I have complete setup for sending SMS. I just need to know how can I fetch unread mails from Gmail, is there any API for this ? what tools I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope its help you to start, great [link](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3380/check-your-unread-gmail-from-the-command-line) about Check your unread Gmail from the command line

```
 curl -u username --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" |
 perl -ne 'print "\t" if /<name>/; print "$2\n" if
 /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

i tried it before some months and its work fine!

Answer (score 1):

I would just pull from the Imap4 or pop3 interface provided by Gmail.

However the user will have to have [Imap/Pop3 enabled](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273) but I assume that is not a problem.

I assume you will be able to find clients for PHP for either of the two

Answer (score 1):

Use php:imap (http://www.php.net/imap) and do a search for UNSEEN messages.

Answer (score 1):

or check google code if they provide an api for checking the unread messages of a user

Answer (score 1):

This [Gmail rss feed with unread email in PHP](http://amitmondal.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/gmail-rss-feed-with-unread-email-in-php/) can help you.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.. while simple, then I would be worried about that Google could change the format or functioning of the RSS feed at any time breaking the applications depending on it -- while using IMAP/POP are standards.